# Handling Historical Balance data containing ONLY changes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2019

I am trying to figure out the best way to handle a database I did NOT build and can't alter.  I have two tables.

tAccount is a list of accounts.  Has acctnum, type, owner, currentbalance

tBalHist is a history of balances for the accounts from tAccount*.  Has acctnum, balance*date, balance

tBalHist *ONLY has records for when the balance changes.  So, if the balance for acctnum 100001 hasn't changed since 8/1/2023 the most current row in tBalHist would be* from 8/1/2023.

If I wanted a query to get the balance for all accounts for the last 7 days (today being 9/1/2023) how might I include the balance for the above referenced account for the last 7 days since there's no balance entry in tBalHist for that time period?

Thanks!

other than filling in those gaps and making my table huge I can't picture a way forward.

tAccount

| acctnum | type | owner | currentbalance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | A | JDoe | 123.74 |
| 34567 | B | MSmith | 3883.56 |
| 45887 | B | NJhonson | 346783.56 |

tBalHist

| acctnum | baldate | bal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 09/01/2022 | 1238.74 |
| 12345 | 09/02/2022 | 1233.24 |
| 12345 | 09/03/2022 | 1263.75 |
| 12345 | 09/04/2022 | 1323.12 |
| 12345 | 09/07/2022 | 123.74 |
| 34567 | 01/08/2023 | 3883.56 |
| 45887 | 05/08/2023 | 346783.56 |

See example tables above.  note today is 9/7/2023.  I want to return the balance history for each account in a table for the last 7 days, with averages as well.

How would I represent the accounts 34567 and 45887 in this query?

Comment: A [mcve] would make this clearer.

Comment: `the balance for all accounts for the last 7 days` -> this is unclear to me. If an account has three balance changes in the last 7 days, do you want one row with the latest balance, or three rows (one for the balance after each change)? If the former, then it seems a simple top n per group, it doesn't really matter if the balance changed in the last 7 days. It's also unclear what balance you're looking for from the history table and how it could be different from `currentbalance` in the account table? As mentioned, tables, sample data (including edge cases), desired results will go a long way.

Comment: The slow way: 1) recursive CTE to make a table with 7 records, today() - 0, today() - 1,... 2) Cross-Join that to your Account table so you get 7 records for every account with each day you want displayed as a separate record. 3) Join to tBalHist on account number with a correlated subquery like Where tBalHistDate=(Select max(x.tBalHistDate) from tBalHist x Where x.tBalHistDate<=AcctDate and x.acctnbr=a.acctnbr). The correlated subquery might be slow.